# pq: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser and rds_superuser connections

Tags: postgresql, go

I keep getting this error:

> pq: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser and rds_superuser connections

I've read many articles, but that's all only give solution from the database's side, not the golang's. I can't change the database config, the max_connections is already in 3500

the process is:
i get the data from calling API, then store the response data to someone's database directly, not by API

ive tried adding time.sleep, reusing http, and pooling http, setting up Transport, but seems this problem has nothing to do with connection.

*i already check, i close the response.Body

## GET:

```
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        MaxIdleConns: 100,
        MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 100,
    },
    Timeout: time.Duration(30) * time.Second,
}

req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", magento_url, nil)
response, err := client.Do(req)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("The HTTP request failed with error %s\n", err)
} 

defer response.Body.Close()

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
if err != nil {
   log.Fatalf("Couldn't parse response body. %+v", err)
}
fmt.Println("Response Body:", string(body)) 

countriesMap := make(map[string]interface{})

err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &countriesMap)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}   

for  key,val := range countriesMap {
     if(key=="items"){
        switch concreteVal := val.(type) {
           case []interface{}:
               fmt.Println(key)
               parseArray(val.([]interface{}))

            default:
                fmt.Println(key, ":", concreteVal)

            }
        }
     }
```

## POST:

```
func parseArray(anArray []interface{}) {
   arrayData := make(map[string]interface{})
   for i, val := range anArray {
       switch concreteVal := val.(type) {
       case map[string]interface{}:
           fmt.Println("Index::", i)

           for key, valLast := range val.(map[string]interface{}) {
               switch concreteValLast := valLast.(type) {

               default:
                   if key=="coupon_code"{
                       arrayData["coupon_code"]=concreteValLast
                   }else if key=="coupon_description"{
                       arrayData["coupon_description"]=concreteValLast
                   }
               }
           }
       default:
           fmt.Println("Index", i, ":", concreteVal)

       }
       dm_connection := []string{"user=",dm_username," password=",dm_password," dbname=",dm_database," port=",dm_port," host=",dm_host};
       db, err := sql.Open("postgres", strings.Join(dm_connection,""))
       if err != nil {
         panic(message)
       }
      defer db.Close()

      var dataField ApiData

      checkingData := `SELECT coupon_code FROM discount WHERE coupon_code = $1`
      err = db.QueryRow(checkingData, arrayData["coupon_code"]).Scan(&dataField.Coupon_code)

            if err != nil {
                if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
                    //INSERT DM
                    InsertDM(db, arrayData)

                }else{
                    fmt.Println(message)
                }
            }
     func InsertDM(db *sql.DB, arrayData map[string]interface{}){

       insertStatement:=`INSERT INTO discount (coupon_code,coupon_description,created_at) VALUES ($1,$2,$3)`
       _,errInsertDM := db.Exec(insertStatement,arrayData["coupon_code"],arrayData["coupon_description"],arrayData["timestamp"])

   // if there is an error inserting, handle it
       if errInsertDM != nil {
           message:=errInsertDM.Error()
          panic(message)
       }

       insertedData++

    }
}
```

i expected it can handle like 15.000 data, but that error always appear in like 3000 data

Comment: The code shown doesn't connect to postgres, so it's unrelated to an error with postgres connections. Most likely you're not closing your connections/results when you're done with them.

Comment: @Adrian halo Sir thank you for replying me. i forgot to showing the POST process. here i already updated it.. the connection with postgres. thanks

Comment: This looks like a mix of code that's missing a lot of context. Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Adrian ok sir. is that enough?

Comment: I think there's some issue with the copy & paste because the code as posted is not syntactically valid, not complete, and not formatted.

Comment: @Adrian ups, sorry for that. but i already checked with my code, this almost look exactly like mine. the different only in some database and api credentials

Comment: Why do you call these POST and GET? It looks like your "POST" code defines the parseArray() function and your "GET" code calls it. But how does the "GET" code gets executed? Is that the main() function?

Comment: @MadWombat sorry for late reply. yep u r right, the GET is in main. so the process is: i call the API to get data, then store the response data to someone's database. the data that i need to store is nested array. 

ex: [ data1,data2,data3[data_that_i_need] ]

Comment: UPDATE:
thanks for all of comments, ive fixed it now.